# What are the steps to solving this ODE?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[Ordinary Differential Equation Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGW9c.png)

From my knowledge, I would get into the form $\frac{d x}{dt}-a(t)x=0.$
Then my Integrating Factor would be $e^{\int_{}^{}-a(t)dt}.$

But I'm confused on how to do this here and where does the greek letter tau even come from?

Comment: $\tau$ is the (dummy) variable of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ODE:

$$ {dx(t) \over dt} - a(t)x(t)=0 \tag 1$$

Can be solved be defining $x(t)$ as a product of two functions $f(t)$ and $g(t)$:

$$x(t)=f(t) g(t) \tag 2$$

Now, insert $(2)$ into $(1)$ to get:

$$ {d \bigg( f(t) g(t) \bigg) \over dt} - a(t)f(t) g(t)=0 \tag 3$$

which can be rewritten as:

$$ {d  f(t)   \over dt} g(t) +{d  g(t)   \over dt} f(t)- a(t)f(t) g(t)=0 \tag 4$$

Now, divide the above equation with $g(t)$:

$$ {d  f(t)   \over dt} +{ {d  g(t)   \over dt} \over g(t)} f(t)- a(t)f(t) =0 \tag 6$$

$$ {d  f(t)   \over dt} + \Bigg ( { {d  g(t)   \over dt} \over g(t)} - a(t) \Bigg ) f(t)=0 \tag 7$$

The idea now is to choose the function $g(t)$ in a smart way so the term ${ {d  g(t)   \over dt} \over g(t)} - a(t)$ is equal to zero. That way we simplify equation $(7)$. By choosing $g(t)$ to be $e^{\int_{t_0}^ta(\tau)d \tau}$ we get:

$${ {d  g(t)   \over dt}} - a(t)g(t)=0 \tag 8$$

$$ a(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^ta(\tau)d \tau} -a(t)e^{\int_{t_0}^ta(\tau)d \tau}=0 \tag 9$$

where $\tau$ is just the [dummy variable](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DummyVariable.html) of integration. Now, equation $(7)$ becomes:

$${ d f(t) \over dt} = 0 \tag {10}$$

which means $f(t)=C$, where $C$ is a constant. Your solution to the ODE $(1)$ is:

$$x(t) = Ce^{\int_{t_0}^ta(\tau)d \tau} \tag {11}$$

where you can determine the constant $C$ from your initial condition.

Inserting $x(t_0)=x_0$ into $(11)$, we get:

$$x_0 = C e^0=C \tag{12}$$

This means the final solution to your problem is:

$$x(t) = x_0e^{\int_{t_0}^ta(\tau)d \tau} \tag {13}$$

Note that instead of the index $i$ I simply used the index $0$.

**EDIT:**

This way of solving an ODE is called the integrating factor method. It is a standard method and it is used to eliminate a term in an ODE in order to simplify it. For example, using the integrating factor method, we can reduce a non-separable ODE of the form:

$$ {dx(t) \over dt} - ax(t) + b=0 \tag {14}$$

to the following [separable](https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/core-mathematics/calculus/separable-first-order-differential-equations.html) form:

$$ {df(t) \over dt} + be^{\int_{t_0}^tadt}=0 \tag {15}$$

As you can see, solving equation $(15)$ is simple compared to solving equation $(14)$.

So to summarize, we decided to write our function as a product of two functions in order to simplify our ODE.

Comment: I understand the working out of the solution but I would like to know how you decided to solve it this way of defining x(t) as a product of 2 functions. Is this a standard method and if so, what is this technique called? I would just like to know so I can learn to do it myself next time.

Comment: I have edited my answer. I hope it's understandable now :D

Comment: Dont forget to accept the answer if it was the one you were looking for :D